# how to put automatically title of page on a slider revolution in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I am using a slider revolution (in wordpress) in my header. I would like to put automatically the name of each page inside the slider without doing in manually...

I tried to had `{{title}}` on my slider but does not seem to work...

Any idea ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

Try this:

1.) Give the layer that will contain the title a class (for example *LayerTitle*). As I remember, the class of the layer can be set under Advanced option.

2.) All that is left is to add the following jQuery code to set the title to that class:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        var title = jQuery(this).attr('title');
        $('.LayerTitle').text(title);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but does not seem to work. I leave {{title}} in my slider right ? I had the jQuery code and I give my layer the ID...

Comment: The layer content will get overriden by jQuery so no need for  {{title}}. You need to use the ID you give the layer inside $('#LayerTitle'). Also, since you have a slider in a header, put the above code in a footer. If it still doesn't work, use Chrome Code inspector too see if you get any JavaScript errors.

Comment: So how do I choose the place where my title will be written inside my slider ?

Comment: Just add a layer on each of the slide. That layer will represent the title. But I just realized, it is better to use a class not an ID, since ID shouldn't get repeated.

Comment: By adding a layer I mean go to Revolution Slider in Dashboard and edit a slide there.

Comment: I think I must missed somethin, it does not work... I had the jQuery code inside the javascript section in the Parameters Slider section right ?

Comment: I have add my class in "Attibutes" in the design part of the slider, it's correct right ?

Comment: When you edit a layer, you have "Advanced params" section. Expand it and you should see text field for setting Classes. You set a class there. Regarding the jQuery code, you should put that in footer.php template, for example, before the ending body tag.

Comment: Thanks for helping! It's not working yet, I will keep trying, I probably missed something ...

Comment: I think I found where my mistake is... the slider is not inside the header but in the top of the page but in the main section... maybe I have to change where I put the jQuery code, not in footer.php anymore ? Thanks

Comment: The code should still work. First, you need to know if that class you defined in the layer in step 1 is present once the page is rendered, Can you find those classes in the browser page source?

Comment: I found the problem! I had to change `$(document).ready(` `by jQuery(document).ready(function($){` since Wordpress does not accept this form of jQuery..; I don't know why but it works now :) Thank you

Comment: I'm glad it works. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution.

Under **Module General Options**

**Content -> Source: Post Based -> Type: Current Post**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under **Slider Settings --> Content Source**, change the type to **Current Post/Page**. Then {{title}} will display the current page's title.